# Continuous Progress Bar

Tags: vb6, progress-bar

Using VB6

I want to show the continuous progress bar during the code running time.

Progress bar continuously should run.  Once the coding process is completed, the progress should be invisible.

How to make a code for the continuous progress bar

Need VB6 code Help

Comment: The "marquee" style wasn't introduced in the common controls progressbar until version 6 (with Windows XP). It's relatively simple to use this style from VB 6, as long as you don't need to support any older operating systems. Otherwise, you'll probably need to write custom logic to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky to do if you have continuously running code, since VB6 is single threaded.

I've tried doing this myself (setting the width of a label control with a coloured background), but the GUI tends not to re-draw.  I ended up dividing the work up into sections and calling `DoEvents` at the end of each section.  The GUI update was rather coarse.

There are ways of running multiple threads in VB6 - but they need very careful handling - and from there you might be able to run code in one thread and update a GUI in another.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd say the right thing to do would be to use a `Timer` control. On each `Tick` event, you update the GUI. A lot easier than trying to use multiple threads in VB 6. That's a nightmare; you're better off porting the entire project if you really need threading.

Comment: Using a `Timer` control is a breeze if you have an entirely event driven program.  The timer events interleave with all the other events.  However, if you have continuously running code ALL events are on hold until the code completes.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally we used the Animation Control didn't we?  I'm not sure but I think it runs on its own thread.  Then there's the WebBrowser control which can be used "chromeless" displaying an animated GIF.

Even Windows Movie Maker can be used to convert an animated GIF to an AVI though it might have limitations in that regard.  Seems like you could easily make a barber pole, "Cylon's Eye," column of falling pixie dust, or any other "I'm busy" indicator you want if the Hourglass Cursor isn't good enough.

Cody Gray's marquee style ProgressBar was a great suggestion though.